Gmail randomly blocks emails containing attachments to be sent through SMTP
We are trying to automate email sending to some of our customers. Each email contains a file (with a proprietary format that is retrieved from our Azure Blob Storage) that should be sent to the corresponding client through the SMTP. They want these files to be attachments rather than sending them a link. Unfortunately, sometimes (randomly), Gmail blocks the emails and giving the following error:
(552, b'5.7.0 This message was blocked because its content presents a potential\n5.7.0 security issue. To review our message content and attachment content...

I have tried different mechanisms (e.g., throttling), but none has worked so far.
Is there a way to fix this issue?

You're seeing a (hopefully) false positive from Google virus scanner. There's no way to disable it so you'll need to find another way. Send email through a different provider, or persuade your customers to accept a link.

zip it, I don't know whether it works. also you can try to put a password protection to bypass the google's scanner

thank you @TangentiallyPerpendicular for replying.
I tested different providers, but all had the same issue. Yahoo was better than the other ones, but it doesn't allow the emails recently created to create an app password anymore, so I can't use it.

thank you @user70 for replying.
I also zipped the files, but still facing the same problem.
